# Find the sentence ends with (numeric)

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript I want to find weather the text ends with Open parentheses numeric close parentheses.NewFolder (0), NewFolder (1) and so on.

After finding I want to increment the number by 1 Like Newfolder(0) to Newfolder(1) , NewFolder(1) to NewFolder(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function that will tell you whether you need to do the rename

```
folderHasParenthesesAndNumber = (folder) => {
    return folder.match(/\(\d+\)$/) != null
} // returns true if it matches, and false if it doesn't
```

Uses regex to match a number between parentheses at the end of the string provided.

To rename, I'll provide a skeleton for it:

```
if(folderHasParenthesesAndNumber(folder) === true){
   // Do the rename
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's how to get the new folder name:

```
newFolderName = (folder) => {
    let incrementNumber = Number(folder.match(/\((\d+)\)$/)[1]) + 1;
    return folder.replace(/\(\d+\)$/, "("+incrementNumber+")")
}; // returns folder name, with the + 1
```

To see it running, see the snippet below:

```js
folder = "input(1)";

folderHasParenthesesAndNumber = (folder) => {
  return folder.match(/\(\d+\)$/) != null;
};
newFolderName = (folder) => {
  let incrementNumber = Number(folder.match(/\((\d+)\)$/)[1]) + 1;
  return folder.replace(/\(\d+\)$/, "(" + incrementNumber + ")")
};

if (folderHasParenthesesAndNumber(folder) === true) {
  console.log(newFolderName(folder))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the substring() and once you get the desired string replace it using the replace() method. Check about these two methods and then apply the logic you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find that out like this:

```
var str = "NewFolder (0)"; 
var res = str.match('\(\d\)');

if(res[0]) {
   console.log('ends with (numeric)');
}
```